# PyQt - merge selected features function

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt, qt-designer

**VERSION QGIS 2.1x**

i realize plugins to do this actions without use toolbar: copy features / paste to layer / merge selected features => define attribute to use in merge.

So, all is okay but i don't find "merge selected features" in PyQt action or others like :

qgis.utils.iface. ???

What is good expression to call "merge selected features" [image] action / button ?
All of this actions are in advanced digitize toolbar.

Comment: Try combine geometry of selected features.

Comment: Combine is one of solution but no attributes selection, just geometry combination. no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE:* *The whole answer is for QGIS v3.x (currently v2.99).*

---

**Copy Features / Paste to layer**

These functions are [now available](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/5578) in QGIS master (v2.99) and will be included in QGIS v3.0. You can use them from your plugin in this way:

```
self.iface.copySelectionToClipboard(source_layer) # A prior selection is expected

target_layer.startEditing()
self.iface.pasteFromClipboard(target_layer)
target_layer.commitChanges()
```

**Merge**

As of now, merge functionality is not exposed through the QGIS Python bindings. However, you could do one of the following:

1. **Port [C++](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L7790) [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L7650) to Python**. For instance, I've done that partially (except attribute handling) in a new plugin I'm developing. See [merge-boundaries](https://github.com/AgenciaImplementacion/Asistente-LADM_COL/blob/master/asistente_ladm_col/utils/qgis_utils.py) function.
2. **Trigger QGIS Merge Selected Features action**. Locate the merge selected features action (button) and trigger it:

   ```
   iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionMergeFeatureAttributes').trigger()
   ```

Comment: Good news ! This new functionnality allows to select what attributes use to merge ?

Comment: to Trigger QGIS Merge Selected Features action i need to import QAction in my plugin python script.

Comment: Do you know why my edit features à not save when à trigger :

self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionSaveEdits').trigger()
self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionToggleEditing').trigger()

Comment: You have methods in iface to access those actions, e.g., actionSaveActiveLayerEdits(), actionSaveAllEdits(), actionSaveEdits(), actionToggleEditing(). Do they work for you?

Comment: i'd already try actionToggleEditing() after trigger actionSaveEdits() and just layer.commitChanges() work...

Comment: Why aren't you using layer.startEditing() and layer.commitChanges()?

Comment: I used it but i report that actionToggleEditing() after actionSaveEdits() don't work in my case. Just layer.startEditing() and layer.commitChanges() already work :)

Answer (score 1):

Chosen solution :

> Trigger QGIS Merge Selected Features action. Locate the merge selected
>   features action (button) and trigger it:

**This code need to work with QAction**

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction

self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionMergeFeature').trigger()
```

To trigger "Merge selected features" from plugin script without click on button.